# Does every set in ZFC have a value when interpreted as a misère game?

Tags: set-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

A misère game is one where a player with no moves wins. The object of the game is to *be presented with a board position in which you cannot do anything*.

If we imagine a two-player game where the players take alternate turns, then we can think of a *game* as being isomorphic to a *set of games that we can choose to present to our opponent*. This means we can represent any game fitting our criteria as a set.

Suppose the value to the player is $+1$ if they win and $-1$ if the opponent wins.

The game $\{\}$ has value $+1$ because the player cannot make any moves and therefore wins.

The game $\{\{\}\}$ has value $-1$ because the player must pick the game $\{\}$ and give it to the opponent, who then wins.

The game $\{\{\}, \{\{\}\}\}$ has value $+1$ because the player picks the game $\{\{\}\}$ (which has value -1), to give to the opponent.

Does every set in ZFC have a value as a misère game? I think the [axiom of regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity), guarantees that there must be some kind of "trace" through any set which has a value in some sense, but I don't know whether it's possible to extend this to a value for the entire set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mainly about set theory; the misère game business is a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring). Note that the outcome of a misère game can be calculated recursively: It's $\mathcal N$, which you called "value $+1$", if there are no moves or there's a move to a $\mathcal P$-position. It's $\mathcal P$, which you called "value $-1$", otherwise. Therefore, all that matters is whether play in the set ends in finite time, so that the induction can get to the base case.

As you suspected, the axiom of regularity/foundation [proves no infinite descending sequence of sets exists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity#No_infinite_descending_sequence_of_sets_exists).

(As an aside, instead of relying on regularity/foundation, the graduate textbook ["Combinatorial Game Theory"](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-146) by Aaron N. Siegel just defines the class of long games inductively using [ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number), so that it doesn't matter if regularity/foundation holds.)

Comment: Is the `[combinatorial-game-theory]` tag appropriate? I assumed "no" based on your answer and removed it.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet Your question is about combinatorial games, and you need to know something about games to understand my answer, even if the key to the answer involves set theory alone. I wouldn't want someone with the same question not to find your post because the CGT tag were missing.